# Postgresql migrate data from jsonb array to jsonb

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Let's say I have a column with this jsonb data :

```json
{
    "indicators": [
        {
            "year": 2019,
            "indicatorsByYear": [
                {
                    "value": 3120,
                    "code": "Nb_h"
                },
                {
                    "value": 18,
                    "code": "S_ppa"
                },
                {
                    "value": 95,
                    "code": "T_occ"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "year": 2020,
            "indicatorsByYear": [
                {
                    "value": 300,
                    "code": "Nb_h"
                },
                {
                    "value": 18,
                    "code": "S_ppa"
                },
                {
                    "value": 55,
                    "code": "T_occ"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "dataProvidedByUser": false
}
```

The idea is to migrate this column to a simplified object like this :

```json
{
    "indicatorsByYear": {
        "2019": [
            {
                "value": 3120,
                "code": "Nb_h"
            },
            {
                "value": 18,
                "code": "S_ppa"
            },
            {
                "value": 95,
                "code": "T_occ"
            }
        ],
        "2020": [
            {
                "value": 300,
                "code": "Nb_h"
            },
            {
                "value": 18,
                "code": "S_ppa"
            },
            {
                "value": 55,
                "code": "T_occ"
            }
        ]
    },
    "dataProvidedByUser": false
}
```

How can I transform the `indicators` array to map object with year as key and `indicatorsByYear` as value.

For info, the maximum number of years that I can have is 11 years (from 2010 to 2020), some columns have all the years others only some.

My attempts with something like that without success

```sql
update site
SET data = data
    || jsonb_build_object('indicatorsByYear',
        jsonb_build_object(
            data -> 'indicators' ->> 'year', 
            data -> 'indicators' ->> 'indicatorsByYear'
        ))
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data -> 'indicators'` is an array, whose elements you need to consider individually and then aggregate back together into an object. You can use [`jsonb_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) and [`jsonb_object_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) respectively for this.

Also, you'll want to remove the old `indicators` key from the `data` column.

```
UPDATE site
SET data = jsonb_set(
  data - 'indicators',
  '{indicatorsByYear}',
  (
    SELECT jsonb_object_agg(el ->> 'year', el -> 'indicatorsByYear')
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'indicators') el
  )
);
```

Comment: I found this useful. Shows how to drill into the array in a jsonb